# JSP Query error

Tags: sql, jsp

```
<%
  sqlStr="select lecturer2.name,newroom.roomno";
  sqlStr+="from lecturer2,newroom";
  sqlStr+="where lecturer2.dept<>newroom.dept and newroom.strength>0";
   sqlStr+="group by lecturer2.name";
  rset=stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
  while (rset.next()) {
%>
   <tr>
     <td><%= rset.getString("name") %></td>
     <td><%= rset.getInt("age") %></td>
     <td><%= rset.getString("dept") %></td>
   </tr>
  <%    
  } 
%>
```

I am encountering an error

> :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "." at
>   column 1

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** put SQL queries into a JSP page. And do **not** put Java code into a JSP page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the string value at runtime?

You are missing spaces from your strings, so they are merging the text together.

```
sqlStr="select lecturer2.name,newroom.roomno";
sqlStr+="from lecturer2,newroom";
sqlStr+="where lecturer2.dept<>newroom.dept and newroom.strength>0";
sqlStr+="group by lecturer2.name";
```

Will result in:

```
"select lecturer2.name,newroom.roomnofrom lecturer2,newroomwhere lecturer2.dept<>newroom.dept and newroom.strength>0group by lecturer2.name"
```

Add some spaces to the end of each line in your strings:

```
sqlStr="select lecturer2.name,newroom.roomno ";
sqlStr+="from lecturer2,newroom ";
sqlStr+="where lecturer2.dept <> newroom.dept and newroom.strength>0 ";
sqlStr+="group by lecturer2.name";
```